# MPMoviePlayerController - how to stop it hiding other items?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

MPMoviePlayerController works almost as i'd like it to, except that it covers over any other on screen items, for example my navigation bar. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its player is based on a UIView, like many othEr things.

Have you tried telling objecTs behind it to get in front, with the following :

- [`bringSubviewToFront:`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront%3a)
- [`sendSubviewToBack:`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sendSubviewToBack%3a)
- [`insertSubview:atIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/insertSubview%3aatIndex%3a)
- [`insertSubview:aboveSubview:`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/insertSubview%3aaboveSubview%3a)
- [`insertSubview:belowSubview:`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/insertSubview%3abelowSubview%3a)
- [`exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/exchangeSubviewAtIndex%3awithSubviewAtIndex%3a)

Since your views are already inserted into your superview, you could easily call `bringSubviewToFront:` once for each view in whatever order you like.

Comment: I've tried this, and they appear at the front initially but are quickly sent to the back (perhaps once the video starts playing). And a navigation bar should always be on top anyway, so it wouldn't make sense that its somehow going above that.

Comment: Ah, tested it myself and I see the problem. The video redraws itself and ignores overlaying items. Honestly not sure how to fix that.

Comment: I wonder if there's an alternative to MPMoviePlayerController that i can use instead?